# Error connecting from .NET 5.0 to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: ssl, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-5

I am really desperate: I need to migrate a .NET 4.7.2 API to .NET 5.0.

In debug-mode on my local Windows 10 machine, everything works fine until I publish it on a Debian 10.9.

I configured and started nginx and when I try to send a `GET`, I get the following exception when connecting with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to SQL Server 2008 R2:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

I tried to add

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

to `openssl.cnf` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#possible-reasons-and-solutions) without success.

I also tried to add HTTPSRedirect to my .NET 5.0 API, without success as well.

Does anybody know how to fix that problem?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 in the title and body, **2008 R2** in your tags - and both of those have reached their end of life well over a year ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: Unfortunately i am unable to upgrade. I need to use what exists...